# Source and destination port of ICMP packet

Tags: linux-kernel, netfilter

I'm writing a packet filter in netfilter. Is there a way I can get the source and destination port of a ICMP packet?

I have extracted icmp_hdr from the sk_buff structure. But I don't see any property from source and destination address?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Port numbers are the way the TRANSPORT layer recognizes which packet belongs to what process at the end systems.
They're used to let the process-to-process delivery work; but ICMP, from a functional point of view, is not a transport layer protocol.

ICMP is a messaging protocol at the Network layer(on top of the IP; [but not really in the transport layer](http://talktoanit.com/e/wp-content/uploads/2009/10/image004.jpg)), it's got a lot of responsibilities but none of them has anything to do with process-to-process delivery, so having a port number there wouldn't make any sense.

Take an example, when you `ping`(ping uses ICMP echo messages) an IP address, which port are you really `pinging`?
The answer is: **no port**, you're pinging the whole station to see if it's alive.

Now, ICMP has many [types of messages](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.commadmn/doc/commadmndita/protocols_internet_ctrlmsgtypes.htm); if you want to filter out, for example, `ping` messages, you should check the field `type` and if it equals `ICMP_ECHO`, you can `return NF_DROP`.